# Scraping mobile phone models with links in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a list of mobile phone models off this website https://www.m1.com.sg/personal/mobile/phones/filters/all-plans/all/all/0/1500/0/0/none

that will list down the models and prices. I have the following code but all the prices are incorrect. They shouldn't be zeros. What did I do wrong?

Also, will it be possible to provide clickable links (that allows users to click on the 'More Info' that takes them to the page with additional information on the phone models) only using beautiful soup? For example:

```
 iPhone XR 128GB
   $ 0 
   More Info
```

---

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html.parser import HTMLParser

url_toscrape = "https://www.m1.com.sg/personal/mobile/phones/filters/all-plans/all/all/0/1500/0/0/none"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_toscrape)
info_type = response.info()
responseData = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(responseData, 'lxml')

Model_findall=soup.findAll("div",{"class":"td three title text-center"})
price_findall=soup.findAll("div",{"class":"td two price text-center"})


for models in Model_findall:
    print('*',models.text.strip())
    print(' ',price.text.strip())
```

What I have retrieved:

```
* iPhone XR 128GB
  $ 0
* iPhone XR 256GB
  $ 0
* iPhone XR 64GB
  $ 0
* iPhone XS 256GB
  $ 0
* iPhone XS 512GB
  $ 0
* iPhone XS 64GB
  $ 0
* iPhone XS Max 256GB
  $ 0
* iPhone XS Max 512GB
  $ 0
* iPhone XS Max 64GB
  $ 0
* ASUS ZenFone 5Q
  $ 0
* ASUS ZenFone Live L1
  $ 0
* BlackBerry KEY2
  $ 0
* BlackBerry KEY2 LE
  $ 0
* BlackBerry KEYone Dual SIM
  $ 0
* Huawei Mate 20
  $ 0
* Huawei Mate 20 Pro
  $ 0
* Huawei Mate 20 X
  $ 0
* Huawei Nova 3i
  $ 0
* Huawei P20
  $ 0
* Huawei P20 Pro
  $ 0
* Huawei Y6 2018
  $ 0
* Huawei Y6 Pro 2019
  $ 0
* iPhone 7 (32GB)
  $ 0
* iPhone 7 Plus (32GB)
  $ 0
* Lenovo Tab 7 Essential (LTE)
  $ 0
* LG G7+ ThinQ
  $ 0
* LG V40 ThinQ
  $ 0
* OPPO AX7
  $ 0
* OPPO Find X (256GB)
  $ 0
* OPPO R17
  $ 0
* OPPO R17 Pro
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy A7
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy A9
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy J4+
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy J6+
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy J7 Duo
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy Note9 128GB
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy Note9 512GB
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy S10 128GB
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy S10+ 128GB
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy S10+ 1TB
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy S10+ 512GB
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy S10e 128GB
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy S9 64GB
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2018) 10.5"
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy Tab A 7.0
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 256GB
  $ 0
* Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 64GB
  $ 0
* vivo Nex Dual Screen Edition
  $ 0
* vivo V11
  $ 0
* vivo Y95
  $ 0
* Xiaomi Mi A2
  $ 0
* Xiaomi Redmi Note 6 Pro
  $ 0
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `price` doesn't appear to be defined anywhere in your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script should give you the required output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.m1.com.sg/personal/mobile/phones/filters/all-plans/all/all/0/1500/0/0/none"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for items in soup.find_all(class_="phone-line"):
    model = items.find(class_="title").text.strip()
    price = items.find(class_="light-blue").text.strip()
    print(model,price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
url_toscrape = "https://www.m1.com.sg/personal/mobile/phones/filters/all-plans/all/all/0/1500/0/0/none"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_toscrape)
info_type = response.info()
responseData = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(responseData, 'lxml')

for tr in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"tr middle"}):
    for model in tr.find_all("div",{"class":"td three title text-center"}):
        model = model.text.strip()
    for price in tr.find_all("div",{"class":"td two price text-center"}):
        price = price.text.strip()
    for info in tr.find_all("div",{"class":"td two description"}):
        for link in info.find_all("a"):
            info = info.text.strip() + ": https://www.m1.com.sg" + link['href'].replace(" ","%20")
    print (model,price,info)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css class and id selectors

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.m1.com.sg/personal/mobile/phones/filters/all-plans/all/all/0/1500/0/0/none"  
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

models = [item.text for item in soup.select('#PhoneListDiv .color-orange')]
prices = [item.text for item in soup.select('.price .light-blue')]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(models, prices)), columns = ['Model', 'Price'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?